# Error in Assets folder while running Cordova Android App (plugin)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing a cordova android app and I'm getting an error while using a calendar plugin from github
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

the error is:

[image]

.....................................

my html file for including JSs

```
<script type=="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type=="text/javascript" src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
<script type=="text/javascript" src="JS/Calendar.js"></script>
<script src="JS/fncs.js"></script>
```

my fncs.js file is:

```
var startDate = new Date(2014,8,24,0,0,0,0,0);
var endDate = new Date(2014,8,27,0,0,0,0,0);
var title = "My nice event";
var location = "Home";
var notes = "Some notes about this event.";
var success = function(message) { document.getElementById("developers").innerHTML = "success";};
var error = function(message) { document.getElementById("developers").innerHTML = "failed";};
window.plugins.calendar.createCalendar(calendarName,success,error);
```

and here's my file structure:

[image]

JS folder >>

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated .. thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova has not been initialised yet. So `window.plugins` is undefined and u´ve got a crash.

instead of plain old javascript, try to put your initialization code inside one of the initialization events such as deviceready: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready

That way you can be sure Cordova is up and running.

Comment: Thank you !! it's finally working ! +1 and absolutely a right answer !